# mysql replace for a text between h2 tags

Tags: mysql

Inside mysql db, I have a field named "Summary" we added html text inside it, i want to search each record for the h2 tag remove the whole tag and the followed  , real example as below

my field will contains something like this

```
        <h2>Summary: S.Res.80  [107th]</h2>
</div>    <div id="main" class="wrapper_std" role="main">
```

so I want the content of the field after the replace like this

```
<div id="main" class="wrapper_std" role="main">
```

the text between h2 tag is not the same for all records, but will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
UPDATE <your table> 
SET <your field> = SUBSTRING_INDEX(<your field>,'</h2>\n</div>    ',-1)
```

That should replace the old value with what you have after the `</div>`